# Android: Catch Error "Unfortunately 'app' has stopped working"

Tags: android, error-handling

is it possible to catch/handle this error and display a different dialog message? 
like:
 Sorry "AppName" has stopped working

Comment: need relevant code and stack trace

Comment: I think he wants to change the dialog that is displayed when an app force closes. I don't think you can do that..

Comment: actually I already fix the error just want to know if its possible to handle that kind of error and display a different message?

Comment: ok thanks, that's what I need to verify :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is possible to customize the Android Force Close Message.Do the Following,

Create your own Exception handler class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(MainActivity.this));

        int y = 5/0;
    }
```

And this is the Class that captures the Force Close Dialog and shows our CustomDialog.

**UnCaughtException.java**

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.io.StringWriter;
 import java.io.Writer;
 import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.Locale;

 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.os.Environment;
  import android.os.Looper;
 import android.os.StatFs;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class UnCaughtException implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {


private Context context;
private static Context context1;

public UnCaughtException(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    context1 = ctx;
}

private StatFs getStatFs() {
   File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    return new StatFs(path.getPath());
}

private long getAvailableInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat) {
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    return availableBlocks * blockSize;
}

private long getTotalInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat) {
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    return totalBlocks * blockSize;
}

private void addInformation(StringBuilder message) {
    message.append("Locale: ").append(Locale.getDefault()).append('\n');
    try {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo pi;
        pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        message.append("Version: ").append(pi.versionName).append('\n');
        message.append("Package: ").append(pi.packageName).append('\n');
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CustomExceptionHandler", "Error", e);
        message.append("Could not get Version information for ").append(
                context.getPackageName());
    }
    message.append("Phone Model ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL)
            .append('\n');
    message.append("Android Version : ")
            .append(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE).append('\n');
    message.append("Board: ").append(android.os.Build.BOARD).append('\n');
    message.append("Brand: ").append(android.os.Build.BRAND).append('\n');
    message.append("Device: ").append(android.os.Build.DEVICE).append('\n');
    message.append("Host: ").append(android.os.Build.HOST).append('\n');
    message.append("ID: ").append(android.os.Build.ID).append('\n');
    message.append("Model: ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL).append('\n');
    message.append("Product: ").append(android.os.Build.PRODUCT)
            .append('\n');
    message.append("Type: ").append(android.os.Build.TYPE).append('\n');
    StatFs stat = getStatFs();
    message.append("Total Internal memory: ")
            .append(getTotalInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
    message.append("Available Internal memory: ")
            .append(getAvailableInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    try {
        StringBuilder report = new StringBuilder();
        Date curDate = new Date();
        report.append("Error Report collected on : ")
                .append(curDate.toString()).append('\n').append('\n');
        report.append("Informations :").append('\n');
        addInformation(report);
        report.append('\n').append('\n');
        report.append("Stack:\n");
        final Writer result = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
        e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        report.append(result.toString());
        printWriter.close();
        report.append('\n');
        report.append("**** End of current Report ***");
        Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(),
                "Error while sendErrorMail" + report);
        sendErrorMail(report);
    } catch (Throwable ignore) {
        Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(),
                "Error while sending error e-mail", ignore);
    }
}


public void sendErrorMail(final StringBuilder errorContent) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            builder.setTitle("Sorry...!");
            builder.create();
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Report",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            String subject = "Your App crashed! Fix it!";
                            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("Yoddle");
                            body.append('\n').append('\n');
                            body.append(errorContent).append('\n')
                                    .append('\n');
                            // sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                            sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                                    new String[] { "coderzheaven@gmail.com" });
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                    body.toString());
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                                    subject);
                            sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                            context1.startActivity(sendIntent);
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setMessage("Oops,Your application has crashed");
            builder.show();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();
}
}
```

Taken from the following tutorial

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/03/13/customize-force-close-dialog-android/

Comment: This actually does work. But I'm sure you just copy/pasted this without even trying it, given the fact that there is html code all over `<span id="IL_AD4" class="IL_AD">`

Comment: @Spring Breaker  is it possible to stop app closing after crash ? and show other activity for example show first activit.

Comment: @mahdi: Yeah it's possible. Just write your `startActivity()` code in the required block instead of showing the dialog.