# Android debugging - How to display UI thread exception/errors categorically as dialog

Tags: android, debugging, exception, android-studio, android-debug

Is there a way to display the exceptions on UI thread (that stalls my app) in a Dialog box categorically every time it happens, anywhere in the code?

Why? : Would help me test my app during times when my phone is not connected to Android Studio (and I can't see the logcat)

So, instead of "MyApp just stopped working" and then going to logcat and finding the error, I can see the stack trace displayed as a Dialog each time exception on UI thread happens

Comment: Are you asking if you can use an app that just crashed (the message is quite clear about that, the app "has stopped working") to recover from that crash and display a Dialog ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There should be an App level exception handler (or something similar), that detects when the app crashes, picks up the error log that made the crash happen (the exception string), and displays as a dialog (possibly scrollable -as it would have a lot of text)

Comment: You can check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010309/android-catch-error-unfortunately-app-has-stopped-working

Answer (score 1):

You can write stack trace into string, and after that show it like dialog, for example:

```
StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
DialogUtils.showErrorDialog(errors.toString()); // call here your's dialog
```