# Android service works only when USB plugged , error occurs after USB disconnected

Tags: android, android-service, instagram-api, android-debug

I am writing a **Android service** that pulls **network data from Instagram** every ten seconds,
and then send a **notification** if there is anything new.

It works very well when **USB debugging** is on, (Can see something on Logcat)
but an error will occur after I disconnect the USB !

I have no idea to debug or check the log what is going on there, 
because error only occurs when Logcat is not working...

> Here are about my service codes (sorry for complexity..)

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // some initializations, fetch the access token, setup the API library ..
        oauthSession = new InstagramOAuthSession(getApplicationContext());
        String accessToken = oauthSession.getAccessToken();
        instagramFacade = new InstagramFacadeImp(accessToken);
        session = new InstagramDataSession(this);
        try {
            followers = session.readFollowers();
            Log.d("myLog", "Read Result: " + followers);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("myLog","Io Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    Log.d("myLog", "Service start");
    handler.post(checkUnfollowedTask);  //task is a runnable
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}


private Runnable checkUnfollowedTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AsyncTaskHelper.runAsyncTask(new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<User>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<User> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    //to pull some network data from instagram
                    FollowInfoViewModel model = instagramFacade.getFollowInfoViewModel();
                    //save data into the internal storage
                    session.saveFollowers(model.getFollowerUsers());
                    return model.getFollowerUsers();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("myLog","Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<User> users) {
                super.onPostExecute(users);
                //some business logics
                Log.d("myLog", "New follower: " + users);
                followers.removeAll(users); 
                Log.d("myLog", "New unfollower: " + followers);
                createNotification(followers);
                followers = users;  
            }
        });

        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);  // invoke every ten seconds
    }
};
```

> Then are all about the logics of creating notifications.

```
private void createNotification(List<User> unfollowers)  {
    if (unfollowers.size() > 0)
        Log.d("myLog", "Unfollower detected, creatre a notification.");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    List<Notification> notifications = buildNotifications(unfollowers);
    for (int i = 0; i < notifications.size(); i++)
        notificationManager.notify(i, notifications.get(i));
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private List<Notification> buildNotifications(List<User> unfollowers) {
    List<Notification> notifications = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    for (int i = 0; i < unfollowers.size(); i++)
    {
        User unfollower = unfollowers.get(i);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doge)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.receive_unfollow_notification))
                .setContentText(unfollower.getFull_name() + "(" + unfollower.getUsername() + ")"+ getString(R.string.unfollowed_you))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build();
        notifications.add(notification);
    }

    return notifications;
}
```

> Please help me to find out the potential error or provide me some ways to debug, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could display Toast or Alert dialog to show errors.. or implement custom exception handler, refer to this answer: [Android: Catch Error "Unfortunately 'app' has stopped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010309/android-catch-error-unfortunately-app-has-stopped-working/18010495#18010495)