# How to get crash report in android without using 3rd party library

Tags: android, crash-reports

I am trying to get the crash log report from my app without using any 3rd party library like `Firebase` etc., Is it possible to create our own crash report methods. I just want to create a `File and Write` it in `SDcard`. Please let me any idea to this.

Comment: see `Thread#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`

Comment: Sure.. I will look on that @pskink

Comment: Yes, if you just want to save the error message in SDcard

Comment: Try checking this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010309/android-catch-error-unfortunately-app-has-stopped-working

On catching errors, you can log it on the SDCard. And via an IntentService, you can upload these Logs to your webserver.

Comment: Thanks @AtishAgrawal.. I think this will work for me.. Let you know once completed..